# Can not send a POST-JSON-Request with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, request

i try to send a POST-JSON-Request with jQuery 1.9.

I always get the following error in Console.

> TypeError: this.products is undefined. this.products.push(oneProduct);

here is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="resources/js/model/Product.js"></script> 
<script>
    function getdetails(){

        var p = new Product(15,11.5,"Pizza Test","P");
        var z = new Product(68,1.5,"Zutate Test","Z");

        p.addOneProduct(z);

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yb_test_post.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: p
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#msg").html( " Post parameter are: <br/>"+msg );
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
```

and Product.js

```
   function Product(id, price, name, type){
    this.id = id;
    this.price = +price;
    this.totalPrice = +price;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.products = [];

    this.addOneProduct = function(oneProduct){
        this.products.push(oneProduct);
        this.totalPrice= this.totalPrice+oneProduct.price;
    };
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should alter your product.js The problem is that you're losing the reference to `this`.

This should do the trick:

```
function Product(id, price, name, type){
    this.id = id;
    this.price = +price;
    this.totalPrice = +price;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.products = [];
    var self = this;

    this.addOneProduct = function(oneProduct){
        self.products.push(oneProduct);
        self.totalPrice= self.totalPrice+oneProduct.price;
    };
  }
```

**EDIT:** When you call the method addOneProduct, the this-reference is correctly resolved. The problem is when actually try to call the service and set p as the data. Upon serializing the object, JS actually calls into the method and at that point the reference is incorrect. What you need to do is stringify the object before assigning it to the data:

```
var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yb_test_post.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(p)
        });
```

Comment: How do you lose the reference to `this`? When you call it like `p.`, it doesn't lose the reference

Comment: I have tried
but now I get another error 
TypeError: oneProduct is undefined self.totalPrice= self.totalPrice+oneProduct.price;

Comment: The `addOneProduct` is a method bound to `this`, so as long as you call the function as a method, `this` shouldn't be lost. - http://jsfiddle.net/Kq6Jw/ . It's different if you did `var a = p.addOneProduct; a();`

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that. My apologies for the oversight

Comment: @user1167253 Your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/Kq6Jw/1/ . Are you sure you're not using this code somewhere else too? Or are you sure the error is referring to the line `p.addOneProduct(z);`?

Comment: Actually, I was right (kind of :) ) See my edit, which solves the problem.

Comment: @Kenneth Oh jeez, I didn't see that line where they're passing `p` in `data`. Good eye :)

Comment: Well, to be honest, I first wrote about the `this` and only after your comment I found out that it was passed in there. So yeah, my first answer was correct, but more because of luck :-D